# Taking lists as input till enter is pressed

Tags: c++, c++11

I am having an integer N.and next N lines contain lists that can have distinct elements from 1-100.But i am not provided length of each list.How to handle this type of input.

If say i have vector > mylist;

I need to populate this list with those lists seperated by just next line.

Say if N=3

```
1 2 3
4
5 6
```

Then mylist[0]=[1,2,3] , mylist[1]=[4] , mylist[2]=[5,6].

How to do it in c++?

Mycode : Not correct but i tried.

```
int main(){
int t;
cin>>t;
cin.ignore();
while(t--){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    cin.ignore();
    lists_t lists;
    std::string record;
    while ( std::getline( std::cin, record ) && 
        record.find_first_not_of( ' ' ) != std::string::npos && lists.size()!=n)
    {
        std::istringstream is( record );

        lists.push_back( std::vector<int>( std::istream_iterator<int>( is ), 
                     std::istream_iterator<int>() ) );
    }

    for ( const auto &l : lists )
    {
        for ( int x : l ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
   }
 }
```

The problem is that if i enter t=1 and n=3 then instead of following n lines it takes 4 lines and then display the data.Why ?

Comment: Guess having a stab at writing C++ code is a good starting point

Comment: So what you need is a `list` of `list` s? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list

Comment: @EdHeal I added code also.Even then its on hold.Can I ask reason?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I added code also Even then on hold.Why?

Comment: @user3903285 If you look at the timings, your edit was a bit too late.

Comment: @user3903285 - As you have added some code I have asked it to be reopened to give it another bite of the apple

Comment: Still not good enough. You should explain what exactly is wrong with your current code, and `not correct` is not really an explanation

Comment: @defaultlocale I mentioned my problem now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use standard function `std::getline` ans string stream `std::stringstream` and of course the container `std::list` itself.

Here is an example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>


int main()
{
    std::list<std::list<int>> lst;
    std::string record;

    while ( std::getline( std::cin, record ) && 
            record.find_first_not_of( ' ' ) != std::string::npos )
    {
        std::istringstream is( record );

        lst.push_back( std::list<int>( std::istream_iterator<int>( is ), 
                         std::istream_iterator<int>() ) );
    }

    for ( const auto &l : lst )
    {
        for ( int x : l ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
1 2 3 
4 
5 6
```

if the input was the same lines.

If you need to enter a given number of lines then the code could look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::list<std::list<int>> lst;
    std::string record;

    size_t n;

    std::cin >> n;
    std::cin.ignore();

    while ( n-- && 
            std::getline( std::cin, record ) && 
            record.find_first_not_of( ' ' ) != std::string::npos )
    {
        std::istringstream is( record );

        lst.push_back( std::list<int>( std::istream_iterator<int>( is ), 
                         std::istream_iterator<int>() ) );
    }

    for ( const auto &l : lst )
    {
        for ( int x : l ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The input could look as

```
3
1 2 3
4
5 6
```

Comment: I'd recommend `std::vector` over `std::list`

Comment: @VladfromMoscow As soon as i enter n the code terminates.Is their no role of n here?

Comment: @user3903285 I have not understood what you are speaking about and what is the n. I showed you code that works.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow Could you please see my post once again

Comment: @user3903285  Why do you enter t and n? What is their meanung? The input will stop as soon as there will not be any more line with data. As for your code then after cin >> t and cin >> n you have to insert cin.ignore();;

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I needto enter N lists t times.So input format is firstline has only t then next line has n then next n lines are showing n lists.which are done t times

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Why it keep on taking input?I want it to be n times only